# How to select and unselect the recycleview in android

Tags: android

I have created the recycleview.That recycleview contains checkbox.If i click the 1 st item in recycleview the checkbox is checked after that i click the 2nd item means the 1 st and 2nd item  checkbox is checked.Its working good but I want to uncheck the 1st checked item if i click the 2nd item  checkbox.`

```
    public static class AddressAdapter1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AddressAdapter1.MyViewHolder>  {
    private int lastSelectedPosition = -1;
    private final Context mcontext;
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
    private AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener onItemLongClickListener;

    public  ArrayList<Child> movieItems;


    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder   {
        public TextView address1,landmark1,building1,others_text;
        public ImageView home,work,others,edit;
        public  CheckBox checkbox;



        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            address1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.address);
            landmark1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.landmark);
            building1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.building);
            others_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.others_text);
            others = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.others);
            home = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.home);
            work = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.work);
            edit = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.edit);
            checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

        }

    }

    public AddressAdapter1(Context mcontext,ArrayList<Child> movieItems ) {

        this.mcontext = mcontext;
        this.movieItems = movieItems;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.profile_list, parent, false);


        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        final Child m = movieItems.get(position);

            holder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (m.getaddress() != null) {
            if (!m.getaddress().equals("null")) {
                holder.address1.setText(m.getaddress());
            }

            if (m.getbuilding() != null) {
                if (!m.getbuilding().equals("null")) {
                    holder.building1.setText("Building/Flatno: "+m.getbuilding());
                }
                if (m.getlandmark() != null) {
                    if (!m.getlandmark().equals("null")) {
                        holder.landmark1.setText("Landmark: "+m.getlandmark());
                    }

                    if (m.getaddress_type() != null) {
                        if (!m.getaddress_type().equals("null")) {

                            String type=m.getaddress_type();
                            if(type.equals("1")){
                                holder. home.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                holder. others_text.setText("Home");
                            }
                            else if(type.equals("2")){
                                holder. work.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                holder. home.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                holder. others_text.setText("Work");
                            }
                            else{
                                holder.others.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                holder. home.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                holder. others_text.setText("Other");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            holder.checkbox.setChecked(m.isSelected());
            holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                    movieItems.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                    final Child m=new Child();
                    m.setSelected(isChecked);


                }
            });
            holder.checkbox.setTag(position);




        }


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return movieItems.size();
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        return position;
    }
}
```

`Logcat error`

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.assertNotInLayoutOrScroll(RecyclerView.java:2186)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$RecyclerViewDataObserver.onChanged(RecyclerView.java:4255)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$AdapterDataObservable.notifyChanged(RecyclerView.java:9945)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(RecyclerView.java:5747)
                                                                             at abservetech.com.foodapp.Checkinpage$AddressAdapter1$1.onCheckedChanged(Checkinpage.java:857)
                                                                             at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:127)
                                                                             at abservetech.com.foodapp.Checkinpage$AddressAdapter1.onBindViewHolder(Checkinpage.java:841)
                                                                             at abservetech.com.foodapp.Checkinpage$AddressAdapter1.onBindViewHolder(Checkinpage.java:709)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5471)
```

`

Comment: Just write a toggleCheckBox() method that simply checks if one is checked, it unchecks it and vice versa

Comment: @Abserve Tech Check your POJO class variable on onBindViewHolder()

Comment: Where you call it?

Comment: do you want to uncheck previous record or second last selected record?

Comment: explain with some example @Eenvincible

Comment: I want to uncheck all previous record @Vickyexpert

Comment: means if I check on 6th record and 1st, 3rd and 8th are already selected then you want to uncheck 1st and 3rd or also 8th ?

Comment: I check the 1st record intially.Then after that i check the 3rd record means the 1st record remains uncheck.next if i check the 6 the record means the 3 rd record will uncheck

Comment: Can you share a screenshot at least to show what you need?

Comment: What to do using POJO class variable @Nisarg

Comment: @Abserve Tech To keep track of selected position

Comment: explain with some example @Nisarg

Comment: @Abserve Tech Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take one boolean in model class :

```
private boolean isCheck;

public boolean isCheck() {
    return isCheck;
}

public void setCheck(boolean check) {
    isCheck = check;
}
```

In onBindViewHolder of Adapter :

```
private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener checkedListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {                      
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int getPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                boolean flag= movieItems.get(getPosition).isCheck();
                 for (int i = 0; i < movieItems.size(); i++) {
                     if (getPosition == i) {
                      movieItems.get(getPosition).setCheck(true);
                      } else {
                      movieItems.get(getPosition).setCheck(false);
                      }
                     }

                notifyDataSetChanged();
               // m.setSelected(isChecked);


                    });;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
     holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
     holder.checkbox.setChecked(movieItems.get(position).isCheck()); 
     holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkedListener);
}
```

Comment: prevoius value not unchecked @Nisarg

Comment: @Abserve Tech you want to check one only at a time ?? right?

Comment: I have posted my logcat error after update your answer

Comment: @AbserveTech try notifyItemChanged(getPosition); instead of  notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @Abserve Tech If this doesn't work let me know we have still one other solution

Comment: May i know your mentioning the holder.checkbox as viewHolder.mCheckBox or anything else

Comment: @AbserveTech In your case holder.checkbox

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118174/discussion-between-abserve-tech-and-nisarg).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private int lastSelectedPosition = -1; // adapter variable

holder.checkbox.setChecked(m.isSelected());
holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
            movieItems.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
            final Child m=new Child();

            if (getPosition != lastSelectedPosition) {
                m.setSelected(isChecked);
                if (lastSelectedPosition != -1) {  
                    movieItems.get(lastSelectedPosition ).setSelected(false) // unselect last selection
                    notifyItemChanged(lastSelectedPosition); // notify adapter
                }   
            }

            lastSelectedPosition = isChecked ? getPosition : -1;  // remember last selected position
        }
    });
    holder.checkbox.setTag(position);
```

**UPDATE**

To avoid RecyclerView exception try to include notifyItemChanged call in an handler:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        notifyItemChanged(lastSelectedPosition); // notify adapter
    }
};
handler.post(r);
```

Comment: How to get the getItemAtPosition in recycleview?

Comment: Your answer working fine as what i'm expecting but this error occurs"Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling" @lubilis