# Checkbox on aplication for tv in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, television

I got a problem. I making a checkbox with setChecked, True and False but i dont know why this not working at all. First i need to call holder.textView. becouse on my aplicaiton checbox is visible but can't be focused. when i make something code like this(working), but when i tring to make some ifs() for handle checked/unchecked everything not work:

```
 case SETTINGS_CHANNELS:
            holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.title.setText(((List<LiveTvChannel>) list).get(position).getTitle());
            holder.title.requestFocus();

            holder.title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
                }
            });

            break;
```

So i try something like this. First i call onClick method for TexxtView and next i call checkbox. But this didnt work. Any1 can help?

```
switch (posit) {
        case SETTINGS_CHANNELS:
            holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.title.setText(((List<LiveTvChannel>) list).get(position).getTitle());
            holder.title.requestFocus();

            holder.title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                            if(!isChecked){
                                holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
                            }else{
                                holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            break;
```

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38526646/3117966)

Comment: thanks for link, but this not working for me

Comment: which error you getting ?

Comment: i cant call method isCheck and setCheck.

Comment: i change movieItems to list and i cant cast methods setCheck and isCheck

Comment: read my answer carefully from top

Comment: still i cant call methods

Comment: Posted and glad to know it worked for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take one boolean in model class :

```
private boolean isCheck;

public boolean isCheck() {
    return isCheck;
}

public void setCheck(boolean check) {
    isCheck = check;
}
```

In Adapter class :

```
private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener checkedListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {                      
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                       int getPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                       boolean flag= list.get(getPosition).isCheck();
                       for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                       if (getPosition == i) {
                       list.get(getPosition).setCheck(true);
                       } else {
                       list.get(getPosition).setCheck(false);
                       }
                       }

                     notifyDataSetChanged();
                    });;
```

In onBindViewHolder of Adapter :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
     holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
     holder.checkbox.setChecked(movieItems.get(position).isCheck()); 
     holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkedListener);
}
```